# Old fantasy/horror tv series identification

Tags: story-identification, tv

TV Series Identification: Each episode tells an isolated and closed story of light terror/fantasy, much like the style of "Tales from the Crypt" (or this way I remember, I was younger).

In one episode a writer invokes a demon, holds him in a circle of protection and forces him to help to write a book telling what the daily routine of hell is like. 
In another episode, a cave scientist (speleologist) or a miner finds a creature in a cave that appears to be a troll. In the end the man manages to escape causing a ray of sunlight to enter through the ceiling of the cave and transform the creature into stone.
The series predates the 2000's.
I've been trying to review this series for years and I can not identify the name to look for it. Thank you any help.

Comment: I don't recognize either of those episodes, but it sounds like it could be [Tales from the Darkside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_from_the_Darkside).

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Some addiitonal info that may apply in this case: Can you narrow things down more than the 20th century? Black-and-white, or color? What country were you in? What language was the show in? Can you recall what channel it was on?

Answer (score 4):

This could possibly be [Monsters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Monsters_episodes), first run from 1988 to 1991.

Episode 12, *Fool’s Gold*, has construction workers who encounter a troll, and episode 22, *Satan in the Suburbs*, has a demon contacting a writer to write Lucifer’s memoirs.